# Design Pattern for interdependent language wrapper

Tags: c#, xml

So for creating structured XML where the structure is defined via a class structure of some sort. Is there a nice design pattern for wrapping the language so that only defined operations can happen?

Each item contains their own XElement)

- MSBuildDoc (the doc generator)
- MSBuildTarget(a target)
- MSBuildMessageTask
- MsBuildCallTask
- MsBuildBuildTask
- MSBuildTaskOutputElement

I'm trying to construct a framework such that orphaning is not possible, only valid combinations work, valid combinations are walkable from an instance of an item.

The interdependence comes in the fact that using `Add(common interface or superclass)`, or `AddAfterSelf(common interface or superclass)`, etc.. methods requires the child/sibling to already be created. If the constructors are public then you can directly create an orphan.

Examples:

```
var msb=new MSBuildDoc();
var mainTarget=new MSBuildtarget(); //created as orphan
msb.Add(mainTarget); // add is free to accept anything even invalid child types
```

**Using  Create methods(static or not) would directly create orphans.**

**Using AddSubType methods requires implementation details of the subType (what is needed to construct it) to live on the parent.**

Examples:

```
var x=new MSBuildDoc();
var mainTarget=x.AddTarget("Main") //AddTarget method is defined in the parent class
  .SetAttributeFluent("BuildInParallel","true");
mainTarget.AddBuildTask(alltargets);
```

I realize that making an exhaustive wrapper is nearly pointless and ridiculous. I am trying to wrap the very few parts that I use in my project so that the core class is very readable and very maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply require that the constructor of each type requires a parameter that is the parent node:

```
var msb = new MSBuildDoc(); 
var mainTarget = new MSBuildtarget( msb ); // constructor calls msb.Add(m_XElem)
```

This pattern is not uncommon when you want to avoid orphaned objects. Alternatively, you could use a full-fledged [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), and have type build and return their potential children.